# Change form_field.required inside UpdateView.form_valid

Tags: django

I have a field with `blank=True`. Inside my `UpdateView` `form_valid` method i have an `if` condition. Is it possible to make it so, if `if cond == False`, the form will act as if the field is required and throw a prompt to fill-in the field, and not a sever error.

**UPDATE**

The logic looks like this:

```
get template.checkbox.value
if template.checkbox.value is TRUE:
  if FIELD is empty:
    if SOME OTHER CONDITION FAILS:
      MAKE FIELD REQUIRED
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have 2 fields such that the validation of one depends on the other, correct?  If so, then you want to use a [`clean()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) to check the 2 fields and then add a validation error on the fields you want a message to appear on.

Comment: No, there's a checkbox. I need to perform ```if checkbox checked``` then if the ```field``` is empty, i need to perform another condition, and only then i need to decide if ```field``` should be required or not.

Comment: If the checkbox is a form field, then `clean()` is what you want.

Comment: Checkbox is not a form field. Is ```clean() ``` aware of request. GET?

Comment: You could hack something together to get access to request.GET, but it'd probably be better to add a checkbox field to the form.